# Es posible agregar a la vista de una entidad otra (no relacionada) como una colección en OpenXava?

Tags: lista, arraylist, hibernate, openxava

Estoy trabajando en OpenXava, actualmente OX cuenta con el módulo "Historia" el cual permite conocer la historia de ciertas acciones en las entidades creadas.

Me gustaría aprovechar la funcionalidad que el módulo Historia proporciona pero como una colección en diversos módulos.

Si tengo Modulo1 me gustaría poder agregar Historia a Modulo1 como una colección.

Lo he hecho con otros módulos pero he utilizado una relación existente, por ejemplo:

**Modulo1** con los campos id,columna1 y columna2
**Modulo2** con los campos modulo1Id,columna1,columna2

Entonces en **Modulo1** puedo agregar la siguiente colección:

```
@ListProperties("...")
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "modulo1Id", ...)
private Collection<Modulo2> listaModulo2;
```

Se podría hacer algo de tal forma que pudiese agregar "**Historia**" como colección filtrando a Historia.getEntidad()=="Modulo1"?

En dónde Entidad es una columna (string) en Historia sin relación con Modulo1.

Muchas gracias por el apoyo.

Answer (score 0):

Es posible usando [@Condition](https://openxava.org/OpenXavaDoc/apidocs/org/openxava/annotations/Condition.html) que permite tener una colección de cualquier entidad con cualquier condición (no necesariamente vinculado a la entidad contenedora), con simplemente un getter (que puede devolver null).

Para tu caso prueba este código:

```
String nombreModulo;

@Condition("${entity} = ${this.nombreModulo}")
private Collection<Historia> getHistoria() {
    return null; 
}
```

Sin @OneToMany, solo @Condition en el getter.

Leete la documentación de referencia sobre colecciones:
https://www.openxava.org/OpenXavaDoc/docs/model_es.html#Modelo-Colecciones

Answer (score 0):

Con la [orientación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/613232) de [@javierpaniza](/users/75510) pude agregar la funcionalidad tal cual y como la necesitaba.

Como complemento, para que funcionase tuve que agregar `@OneToMany` en la colección o no reconocía el "tipo" de la misma.

Con eso y con `@Condition`, funciona perfecto.

Comment: Si eres el mismo usuario que formuló la pregunta, considera solicitar [fusionar tus cuentas](/contact) en _Problema de Cuenta_ > _Necesito combinar perfiles de usuario_.

Comment: Si lo haces, considera [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) la respuesta que te ha sido más útil.